# Customizing a text view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitextview, customization

In my application i have a text view with a large content which shows some help tips for the user.In that text view i have to make bold some titles.can i set it in my interface builder?anyone have idea?is it possible with any other uiobjects like uilabel or something?I tried with an image view but it is not clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436839/uitextview-rich-text

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the text view to show help tips I assume it is non editable. If you want richer formatting in this case then I think UIWebView  offers better solution, as it supports entire HTML markup. So you can use bold, italics and pretty much everything that CSS offers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `UIFont`. You can set the `font` property or text, and assign it to your label/textview/etc.. with the `setFont` property.

```
UIFont* boldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
UIFont* italicFont = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
```

Please read through the [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of `UIFont` !

---

Note: `UITextView` allows only a single uniform font for all text. If you want different font size I would suggest that you create separate `UILabel` and `UITextView` and add them as subviews to your `self.view`, and align them perfectly. This should solve the problem.  But if you want to use only one object for this operation, I would suggest `UIWebView`, or `CoreText` or may be `CATextLayer`'s `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: I think the OP wants to use both in the same textbox.

Comment: @Paul.s I am sorry, which both ?

Comment: Some bold titles and then some non bold text. Granted it's not the clearest question but thought I would try save you getting the stroppy down votes people love to give. The hint for me was `... some titles`

Comment: @Paul.s Sorry, I did not think that might also be the question... Its now edited.

Comment: now i added the labels separately for the titles and the content in a scroll view.can i justify the content inside this scroll view?

Comment: @Paul.s,can i align both left and right of a text view or a label?any tricks

Comment: Yes you can align any object you want. Set the `frame` with proper x and y values. ...