# Different text formats in UITextView ? Or something else?

Tags: objective-c, ios, format, uitextview

I want to set different text formats (normal, bold, italic...) or HTML in the same text view. Is it possible with UITextView ? Or what else ?

Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this in Stack over flow

There's also an undocumented `-[UITextView setContentToHTMLString:]` method.

But people say the app will be rejucted if you use un documented methods see this stackoverflow link [Display html text in uitextview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454067/display-html-text-in-uitextview)

Please have a look at this too 
[is there anyway to display HTML content in textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998030/is-there-anyway-to-display-html-content-in-textview)

This too [UITextView Rich text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436839/uitextview-rich-text)

stack overflow have lot more please search inside stackoverflow..

Comment: Thanks and sorry for this. Of course, this is a professional app, so I have to only use documented methods. Thanks for your advices ;)

Comment: Welcome.. Yes you have to use only legal methods...;)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?, you can use pure HTML since it is a full working browser